# How can I change the way a lodash function is used for Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
    _.remove(this.home.modal.data.roles, function (currentObject) {
        return currentObject.name === roleToDelete;
    });
```

Can someone tell me how I can change the function call to the way it's usually done with Typescript. Also it gives me an error:

```
    Message 118 TsLint: expected callSignature to have a typedef.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I'm remembering correctly, but try adding `boolean`, i.e. `function (currentObject): boolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
_.remove(this.home.modal.data.roles, (currentObject) => {
    return currentObject.name === roleToDelete;
});
```

You can also type your "currentObject" like this:

```
_.remove(this.home.modal.data.roles, (currentObject: Role) => {
    return currentObject.name === roleToDelete;
});
```